# appspec.yml does not execute scipts

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-pipeline, aws-code-deploy-appspec

I am building the code pipeline using aws code pipeline and for that I build a appspec.yml file to deploy on server the appspec files portion work correctly and bring the code from source to destination and then It does not execute the Scripts in the script folder of the code and also does not give any error

here is appspec.yml

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: /
    destination: /home/ubuntu
    file_exists_behavior: OVERWRITE
hooks:
ApplicationStop:
      - location: scripts/stop_server.sh
        timeout: 300
        runas: root
        
BeforeInstall:
      - location: scripts/deploy_server.sh
        timeout: 300
        runas: root
       
ApplicationStart:
      - location: scripts/start_server.sh
        timeout: 300
        runas: root
```

and here is the script file

```
#!bin/bash

sudo systemctl stop HYPNOS.service

sudo systemctl disable HYPNOS

sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need **indentation** after `hooks`. It should be:

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: /
    destination: /home/ubuntu
    file_exists_behavior: OVERWRITE
hooks:
  ApplicationStop:
      - location: scripts/stop_server.sh
        timeout: 300
        runas: root
        
  BeforeInstall:
      - location: scripts/deploy_server.sh
        timeout: 300
        runas: root
       
  ApplicationStart:
      - location: scripts/start_server.sh
        timeout: 300
        runas: root
```